Wraps C Executable with Rust FFI
This Rust executable passes its arguments - including the executable's path - to an existing C program via Rust's FFI.
From a human's perspective, invoking the built executable should be identical to invoking the original.
The main function of the C program has been renamed to main_legacy to avoid conflicting with rust's main function.
The C code is being compiled and linked in build.rs.
I am curious if there is a cleaner, more idiomatic way of implementing the interface between languages than done below. Alternatively, if there are core Rust concepts I have missed or am misusing, that would be helpful to know.
Long term, I will be replacing portions of the library with Rust and this was meant to test the build process and to learn Rust best practices.
use std::env::args;
use std::ffi::{c_int, c_uchar, CString};

extern "C" {
    pub fn main_legacy(argc: c_int, argv: *const *const c_uchar) -> c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let args = args();

    let arg_bytes: Vec<_> = args
        .map(|arg| Vec::from(CString::new(arg).unwrap().as_bytes_with_nul()))
        .collect();

    let arg_ptrs: Vec<_> = arg_bytes.iter().map(|arg| arg.as_ptr()).collect();

    let argc = i32::try_from(arg_ptrs.len()).unwrap();

    unsafe {
        main_legacy(argc, arg_ptrs.as_ptr());
    }
}

Here is the C function that is being invoked. Formally this was simply "main" but it conflicted with the "main" in rust.
int main_legacy(
    int argc, 
    const unsigned char* const *argv
);


@BillalBegueradj Thank you! Do my updates address the issue?

I have also added the function I am invoking.

I also renamed a bit so it was clearer what I was trying to accomplish.
